# Checking for the presence of an element one every page

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Here's the scenario i am testing a web application and the first thing i have to do is to write a test that checks the presence of 'report no.x' on every page.
Note : The value of X changes from page to page like on home page it is 1 on other page it is 3 etc.
Is there any way that i can do it reducing my number of lines of codes.Like instead of writing IF Else for every page i navigate to can there be a solution where i may have to write If else only once and that block gets executed everytime a new page is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the desired behaviour through combination between page object pattern and base class.

```
public class BingMainPage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;
    private readonly string url = @"http://www.bing.com/";

    public BingMainPage(IWebDriver browser)
    {
        this.driver = browser;
        PageFactory.InitElements(browser, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sb_form_q")]
    public IWebElement SearchBox { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sb_form_go")]
    public IWebElement GoButton { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "b_tween")]
    public IWebElement ResultsCountDiv { get; set; }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.url);            
    }

    public void Search(string textToType)
    {
        this.SearchBox.Clear();
        this.SearchBox.SendKeys(textToType);
        this.GoButton.Click();
    }

    public void ValidateResultsCount(string expectedCount)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(this.ResultsCountDiv.Text.Contains(expectedCount), "The results DIV doesn't contains the specified text.");
    }
}
```

If this is one of your pages you can create a base class to derive from. There you can have the X value property and your wait method. The child classes should derive from this class and pass the exact value of X. This way you can reuse the logic in all of your tests.

You can find more detailed examples here: http://automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton . Why didn't that come to my mind :p

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works for you. If this solves your problem. Can you please rate and close the question because it is still in the unanswered queue?